# How I can call a file in CodeIgniter, that has existed in core folder

Tags: codeigniter

I am a absolute beginner of CodeIgniter, Now I was creating a simple project with CI. But I don't know how I can call a file that has existed in core folder.

Core folder is like the following

```
/core/bootstrap/bootstrap.css
```

I want to call `bootstap.css` from my `view/admin/index.php`

How I can call it?

I already try it like the following

```
<link href="/application/core/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: look at documentation and read about [url_helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: Let us know if you can get it to work or not! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not put your CSS files in the core folder. Best practice with CI is the following:

```
- application
- assets
 -- css
 -- js
 -- images
- system
 -- <all CI folders here>
```

Use a URL helper to point to the assets folder like:

```
function asset_url(){
    return base_url().'public/';
}
```

more info on [url_helpers](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Then you can point to your assets in your view like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<?php echo asset_url()."css/YOUR_FILE.css" ?>'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at documentation and read about [url_helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

Use internal links with function `site_url()` or `base_url()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all I will not put my css files in the core folder.
I will create folder which is in the same level as in the "application" and "system" folder.

Secondly, you need to configure the base url at application/confi/config.php like

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/NV/';
```

With in the folder "NV", I have my CI files such as "application" and "system".

Then in the view I will just use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/ace.min.css"/>
```

In this case, the "CSS" folder resides as in the same level as "application" and "system" folders.